# Java Spring Boot Security + mongoDB user registration (authentication and authorization)

Tags: mongodb, authentication, spring-security, authorization

I am pretty new to Spring Boot and programming in general. I want to create a registration and login using spring security and mongodb as its database. Right now I am storing the user's role upon registration with username and password.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Document("user")
public class AuthUser {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Indexed
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String role;
}
```

Should I be storing the the user's role upon registration? The application I am trying to make should only have two different types of users, so I am planning on designating their roles upon creation and then they can access their respective end points and resources. What are the best practices for spring security with mongodb? I am having so much trouble finding any working resources with spring boot and mongodb.

This is my config settings:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/register","/error").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/usera**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USERA")
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/userb**").hasAuthority("ROLE_USERB")
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults())
.build();
```

This is my service:

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class AuthUserDetailService implements UserDetailsService {
    @Autowired
    private AuthUserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<AuthUser> authUserOptional = userRepository.findByUsername(username.toLowerCase());
        if (authUserOptional.isEmpty()) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        AuthUser authUser = authUserOptional.get();
        String role = authUser.getRole().toUpperCase();

        return User.builder()
                .username(authUser.getUsername())
                .password(authUser.getPassword())
                .authorities("ROLE_" + role)
                .build();

    }
}
```